# Pocketbase with Wails

Tags: go, pocketbase, wails

How to package pocketbase with a windows application built with wails. Such that the build application when launched creates a pb_data folder with the db in it, and the application can interact with the db using pocketbase SDK.

For a personal project so security or performance is not a consideration.

Open to any suggestions

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.